# Chaining adjacent sibling operator in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is the following

```
.a + .b + .c
```

a valid selector for an element of class `c` that directly follows two elements of class `a` and `b` respectively? It seems to work in Chrome 16. Is it clear from the standard, that it should work?

Comment: Yes it is. FF + Chrome + Safari + Opera + IE9

Comment: Why do you think it's non-standard to use multiple combinators? We combine combinators (ha!) every day: `nav > ul > li a` and the adjacent sibling combinator is a CSS2 selector which has been standardized for a good while, along with the child and descendant combinators.

Comment: @micha: Might as well take out the version number from IE too, now that IE6 hardly matters to most anymore.

Comment: http://www.whatwg.org/ use `+` selector on there start page!

Comment: Yes, the `+` selector is nothing new and nothing to be excited about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Works fine for me and is standard, as far as I know.  (Have never seen anything to the contrary)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6ykxB/

If it were just utilizing the last adjacent selector, this would still work

`.z + .b + .c`

but it doesn't

Example2: http://jsfiddle.net/6ykxB/1/

A reference on SitePoint mentions multiple adjacent sibling selectors, a further confirmation that they are standard:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector

However, there is a warning for elements with `:hover` and multiple selectors:

> Safari (up to and including version 4) and Chrome (up to and including
>   version 3) behave “buggily” when the adjacent selector is preceded by
>   an element using the :hover pseudo class. The bug varies between
>   versions but the rule is either not applied at all, or applied
>   inconsistently.

Comment: WebKit still has trouble with adjacent and general sibling combinators when used with `:hover` even in the latest versions, so we still have to be careful. However this has nothing to do with the usage of multiple combinators: `:hover` is a pseudo-class, not a combinator. It has issues in WebKit even with just one `+` or `~`.